# How do I know that the answered questions are from the section as and how to calculate them

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

**My scenario:**

I have a form with several sections, each section contains 4 questions with an optional "yes" option. [link google forms](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfOkG0aTUFT8pIbYPPZUQ2LgI2zqFzuuci8OdUvFTSucizUlw/viewform)

```
  section 1   |   section 2   |    section 3     |     section 4     |     section 5      
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 
y       y       y   y   y   y       y                   y    y    y
```

**My result:**

As per the outline above, I would need to have a list with the sections and their yes counts [link google spreadsheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Kfg5W4QWe8Pmyd6oq--tAbTjDH8_sHr0-Pf7qVnyGJQ/edit?usp=sharing)

**My need:**

```
sec. 1 | sec. 2 | sec. 3 | sec. 4 | sec. 5
2      | 4      | 1      | 3      | 0
```

I would like to count only the questions marked "yes" for each section, but I do not have the section line in the google spreadsheet linked to the Google Form.

Answer (score 0):

There is a easy way of doing this operation by first changing the answer to boolean values (y→1, n→0) as this:

```
  section 1   |   section 2   |    section 3     |     section 4     |     section 5      
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 
1       1       1   1   1   1       1                   1    1    1
```

Then you can use the function [`COUNT()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093620) under each section to get the number of *true* values. Please, ask me any question to further clarify this answer.

Comment: "but I do not have the section line in the google spreadsheet linked to the Google Form"

Comment: Hi there @RenatoDolza! I don't comprehend your situation. You could try to change the values by *find and replace* (`CTRL`+`H`). If that doesn't help, please share a copy of your sheet so I can help you better.